# How fetch data by distinct column and count of column in spring data jpa?

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a postgresql table as follow:

```
------------------+------------------------+------------------------
      id          +        username        +      sessionId
-------------------------------------------+------------------------
      1           +  admin                 +   sfs02asdf02sadf92sfda
      2           +  admin                 +   2adfasdfhjlweashfuwaf
      3           +  ali                   +   23asfdadsfhkjiwuqeoas
      4           +  admin                 +   aadfhlajdfjkasdh27ask
      5           +  ali                   +   hadsuiadsfhkioasdkfha
```

Now I want to fetch data as follow:

page: 1, pageSize: n:

```
[
   ['admin', 3, 'sfs02asdf02sadf92sfda'],
   ['ali', 2, '23asfdadsfhkjiwuqeoas'],
   ...
]
```

How can I fetch data as follow in Spring data jpa?

**Note**: First item is `username`, second is `count of username` and third is `first sessionId`.

Comment: I would use JdbcTemplate for this SQL aggregation query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Data JPA, I hope you know the Pagination Implementation. Now for your queries, you can write `Native Queries` and that will go into Pagination implementation.

```
@Query(value = "select 'expected value' * from Table", nativeQuery = true)
Page<Map<String, Object>> findSessionId(@Param("userId") Integer userId, Pageable pageable);
```

Then,
    You can have a function to access the output value and return to the controller.

The tricky part is if you write proper SQL then no need to do anything in your service layer or else you should do some workaround from in service layer.